# Query to find all the subscribers from a child business unit who joined during a specific time frame

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, subscriber, child-to-parent, sfmc-business-unit

I am trying to query all the subscriber from a child business unit who joined during a specific time frame.

Here's my SQL below

```
Select
    s.SubscriberKey,
    s.EmailAddress,
    s.DateJoined
    from [_Subscribers] s
    where
    DateJoined between '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-31'
```

When I run this query above, the output I got was really a smaller number.

Total subscriber count I got was 12K, whereas the actual numbers should be somewhere around 300K. Something is wrong, but not sure what it is! Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You should be querying ent._subscribers

Comment: Thanks for your response 
I already tried the query with 'ENT.', but I got an error that "ENT._subscribers" is not a valid system data extension.

Comment: Do you not have a view of the subscribers/contacts in a DE you normally send to for that BU? By default, there is no easy way to retrieve subscribers in BU level, hence custom solution is required. 

If you do have subscribers in a master DE you could then join with ENT._subscribers to get the lastjoined date and get those sub counts.

Comment: Did you have subscribers in brackets? If so remove the brackets

Comment: How do you 'link' these subscribers to this child BU? Couldnt it be that the first engagement with them occurs from the parent BU?

Answer (score -2):

Use _Listsubscribers this will work